# Read stdout/stderr from subshell to parent

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, stdout, fifo

In a shell script, I want to write to the stdin of an external process X using a named pipe, and I want to send the stdout/stderr from another named pipe to the current terminal.

The external process X is receiving stdin via PIPEIN and it's sending it's stdout/stderr to PIPEOUT.

```
tail -f $(tail -F PIPEOUT) &  # (1) this is completely wrong, need help here

for i; do
    echo "${i}" > PIPEIN  # send stdin to X
done

echo "[stdin end]" > PIPEIN  # signal that we are done writing (there might be a better way lol)
```

So in the above script, we have already started process X, it's been running for some time. But now, when we run the above script we want to send X some stdin and we want to read in the stdout from process X, using PIPEOUT.

What I am trying to do above is set-up a read on PIPEOUT before sending stdin to X, to make sure I capture all of the stdout/stderr of X. The problem is that I don't know how to run some background process (tail or cat to read from PIPEOUT) and send that stdio to the current terminal.

Does anyone know what I am talking about. If I am not mistaken, I just need to fix line labeled (1) and somehow setup a read in the background that can read from PIPEOUT and send that stdio to the current terminal/tty somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear on what you meant `tail -f $(tail -F PIPEOUT) &` to do. It's `tail -f`ing the file that [is the result of](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) `tail -F`, which conventionally never terminates. My assumption is that you want to output everything that comes through the pipe, however long that takes.

The issue with just `tail -f` is that it has to find the end of the file before it outputs anything, which for the pipe never happens. You can [give `tail` an explicit start point instead with `-n +x`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html), picking the line to start at (from the start, 1-indexed). `tail -n 1 -f foo` will display everything it can get from `foo`.

```
tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' < PIPEIN > PIPEOUT & # for example
tail -n +1 -f PIPEOUT &
for i in a b c d ; do
    echo $i > PIPEIN
done
echo "[stdin end]" > PIPEIN
```

Do note, however, that `echo > foo` will close foo after writing the line — the command on the other end will need to be happy to deal with that. If this example is artificial and the real input comes from somewhere else, you can disregard this.

---

Note also that **the `tail` process will never terminate** — it keeps expecting that something more might come through the pipe. You'll have to kill it explicitly yourself, perhaps with your shell's job control. If there's some pattern to the output that would indicate it was done, you might find [`retail` ("tail with regular expressions")](https://github.com/mwh/retail) useful — `retail -n +1 -f -u REGEX PIPEOUT` will terminate when a line matching `REGEX` appears. <sub>(As a disclaimer, I wrote `retail` several years ago for this exact purpose)</sub>

Comment: Thanks, it's ok that tail -f won't end, the user can terminate it in this case manually...although it would better if there were a command that could capture all the stdio from X and then close, as X has a definite end. Maybe cat is better than tail, then.

Comment: If my original question wasnt clear, I am just looking for a command that can read the stdout/stderr from a named pipe, in some sort of streaming fashion. After I figure out that, I need to run it in the background, but still send the stdio from the background process to the terminal if that makes sense.

Comment: `tail`'s output has always been going to the terminal.

Comment: I am trying my best but I don't follow...is there a way to pipe data from a subshell to the parent? Does you answer already cover that?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? I can't tell you what you wanted, only what was in the question.

Comment: My apologies I think I mean pipe data from background process to parent, not subshell to parent.

Comment: Yeah I have to go sleep but will work w this tomorrow, thanks for your help

Comment: not sure why, but the tail command above seems to do the trick. not sure how that works, because I thought it would be running the background (&). However, I frankly do not understand what this line is supposed to do: tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' < PIPEIN > PIPEOUT &

Comment: I wonder if I delete the named pipe, if tail -f will end in that case (probably with an error). Or maybe there is a cleaner way to dry up a pipe.

Comment: It's the background command, as an example, so that the whole code block runs with the right (and visible) effect.

Answer (score 0):

By only opening PIPEIN for writing once, the program terminates - even if there is a 2 second delay:

```
mkfifo PIPEIN PIPEOUT
tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' < PIPEIN > PIPEOUT & # for example
tail -n +1 -f PIPEOUT &
(
for i in a b c d ; do
    echo $i
done
sleep 2
echo "[stdin end]"
) > PIPEIN
```

If you open the fifo several times, then it may be seen as closed by the reader of the fifo, and thus the writer will be hung until another reader comes along to read from the fifo.

So the save bet is to only open PIPEIN once. Otherwise you may see that the program locks up.

Comment: sorry I do not follow